# If i lost the JSF Session scope i want to change to the login page

Tags: session, jsf-2

I used JSF 2.2 Mojarra and the Session Scope.

After some time the Session Scope is delete or something else. If I go back to the login page and login again I have a new Session Scope and everything worked again.

If I worked on the web application the Session Scope is not lost, and I have no problem. So I think it must be lost after some time if I don't use the web application.

Any idea how can I automatically go back to the login page if I lost the session scope?

Comment: You can setup session timeout related values in _web.xml_ + you can use filter for automatic redirection to login page after session timeout.

Comment: Thank you. Have you an example code? Or a link to an example?

Comment: My filter is more complex than you need. Try setup redirection after ViewExpiredException. Maybe it is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expect this first your state saving method should be set to server like below

```
    <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
       <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

After this you should have a session time out like below in your web.xml

```
     <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
     </session-config>
```

If you are idle for more than 20 minutes and if try to make any request from the page then you would see a exception stack trace of ViewExpiredException. Now to redirect to the login page on this you have a have the following config in web.xml

```
    <error-page>  
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>  
        <location>your login page path</location>
    <error-page>
```

This would work if you make a non ajax request from the page after session time out.  Now to make it to work on click of a an ajax button it requires special exception handler for exceptions on ajax requests. you can use `<pe:ajaxErrorHandler>` from primefaces extension library.

To use this you need to have following in your faces-config.xml

```
     <application> 
     <el-resolver>       org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

    <factory>
      <exception-handler-factory>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory> 
     </factory>
```

And primefaces extension namespace `xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"`.

Now in your page just have `<pe:ajaxErrorHandler />` in your page. This would navigate to login page on ajax button click in a page after session time out.

For automatic navigation to login page on time out you can use `<p:idleMonitor>` Something like

```
           <p:idleMonitor timeout="6000" onidle="idleDialog.show()" />
```

Please have a look at this question for correct implementation of idle monitor
[Timeout via idlemonitor (primefaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519675/timeout-via-idlemonitor-primefaces)

If you are using icefaces please visit the following link
[JSF Session timeout and auto redirect to login page without user intraction eventhough Ajax push is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450158/jsf-session-timeout-and-auto-redirect-to-login-page-without-user-intraction-even)

You can also use omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler, Please google for this.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you. I thnik the idelMonitor is good for my problem. I edit this in my page and i get the idleDialog. If i klick on the dialog i looks like it works. But i don't change to the loginpage. I tested for this problem and give feedback if it works